# How to sum fields sql time in JasperReport?

Tags: mysql, time, jasper-reports

I hope you could help me with this problem. I'm using iReport Designer 5.6. I want to create a report like this:

```
Trabajador: A
Fecha   Horas tardanza
20/03   00.20
21/03   00.50
22/03   00.15
-----------------------
Total:  01:25

Trabajador: B
Fecha   Horas Tardanza
22/03   00.02
-----------------------
Total:  00.02
```

I extract the data from MySQL. 'Trabajador' field is a group and type of 'Horas Tardanza' is Time. I created a variable 'total' (Variable Class: java.sql.Time , Calculation: Sum and Variable Expression: $F{Horas tardanza})

But when I see the Preview, Total is 00.00 in all groups Trabajador, except for groups which only contains one register (like Trabajador: B). In groups with one register, Total is ok.
The definition of variable is:

```
<variable name="total" class="java.sql.Time" resetType="Group" resetGroup="trabajador" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="trabajador" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{horas_tardanza}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>
```

And the definition of textfield what contains the variable is:

```
<textField evaluationTime="Auto" pattern="HH.mm">
        <reportElement x="460" y="0" width="92" height="20" uuid="9e47430b-4de5-4f1b-9f2f-ef5af4928385"/>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Arial" size="12"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{total}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```